# error when using flutter with Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

If you use flutter in android studio, all the Widget ls colored with yellow(some color) and some times they recommend commands. Mine worked too, but after resetting flutter sdk, it doesn't work. At first, I thought sdk was wrong, but there's nothing wrong with running code.

For example, if you make code like this,[image]

'build' and 'ThemeData' are colored with yellow.
And if you type 'Colors.' then it recommends some colors which you can use. [image]

However, in my android studio.. it does not works.
I also check my preferences but I can't find the reason.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Try restarting Android Studio and your computer
2. Also, check if dart and flutter SDKs are properly configured for the project.
3. If all this seems good, check if you have accidentally uninstalled Flutter or Dart plugin in Android Studio, if yes install again and restart Android Studio.
4. If they are already installed try reinstalling them and restart Android Studio.

I hope this fixes your problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it still does not works.